# how parallel fetch data from MySQL with Sequel Pro in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r, parallel-processing

I want to fetch data from mysql with seqlpro in R but when I run the query it takes ages.
here is my code :

```
old_value<- data.frame()
new_value<- data.frame()
counter<- 0
for (i in 1:length(short_list$id)) {
mydb = OpenConn(dbname = '**', user = '**', password = '**', host = '**')
query <- paste0("select * from table where id IN (",short_list$id[i],") and country IN ('",short_list$country[i],"')  and date >= '2019-04-31' and `date` <= '2020-09-1';", sep = "" )
temp_old <- RMySQL::dbFetch(RMySQL::dbSendQuery(mydb, query), n = -1
query <- paste0("select * from table2 where id IN (",short_list$id[i],") and country IN ('",short_list$country[i],"') and date >= '2019-04-31' and `date` <= '2020-09-1';", sep = "" )
temp_new <- RMySQL::dbFetch(RMySQL::dbSendQuery(mydb, query), n = -1)
RMySQL::dbDisconnect(mydb)
new_value<- rbind(temp_new,new_value)
old_value<- rbind(temp_old,old_value)
counter=counter+1

base::print(paste("completed for ",counter),sep="")
}
```

is there any way that I can writ it more efficient and call the queries faster because i have around 5000 rows which should go into the loop. Actually this query works but it takes time.

I have tried this but still it gives me error :

```
    #parralel computing 
    clust <- makeCluster(length(6))
    clusterEvalQ(cl = clust, expr = lapply(c('data.table',"RMySQL","dplyr","plyr"), library, character.only = TRUE))
    clusterExport(cl = clust, c('config','short_list'), envir = environment())
    new_de <- parLapply(clust, short_list, function(id,country) {
for (i in 1:length(short_list$id)) {
      mydb = OpenConn(dbname = '*', user = '*', password = '*', host = '**')
      query <- paste0("select * from table1 where id IN (",short_list$id[i],") and country IN ('",short_list$country[i],"') and source_event_date >= date >= '2019-04-31' and `date` <= '2020-09-1';", sep = "" )
      temp_data <- RMySQL::dbFetch(RMySQL::dbSendQuery(mydb, query), n = -1) %>% data.table::data.table()
      RMySQL::dbDisconnect(mydb)
      return(temp_data)}
    })
    stopCluster(clust)
    gc(reset = T)
    new_de <- data.table::rbindlist(new_de, use.names = TRUE)
```

I have also defined the list of short_list as following:

```
short_list<- as.list(short_list)
```

and inside short_list is:

```
id.  country 
2     US
3     UK
...   ...
```

However it gives me this error:

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
one node produced an error: object 'i' not found

However when I remove i from the id[i] and country[i] it only give me the first row result not get all ids and country result.

Comment: Perhaps `clusterMap(clust, function(id, country) { ... }, short_list$id, shortlist$country)`?

Comment: Actually I add for loop inside the parLapply and include i could you please check still does not work

Comment: Sorry, I missed the inner `for` loop ... (indentation threw me, my bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an alternative is to upload the ids you need into a temporary table, and query for everything at once.

```r
tmptable <- "mytemptable"
dbWriteTable(conn, tmptable, short_list, create = TRUE)
alldat <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste("
  select t1.*
  from ", tmptable, " tmp
    left join table1 t1 on tmp.id=t1.id and tmp.country=t1.country
  where t1.`date` >= '2019-04-31' and t1.`date` <= '2020-09-1'"))
dbExecute(conn, paste("drop table", tmptable))
```

(Many DBMSes use a leading `#` to indicate a temporary table that is only visible to the local user, is much less likely to clash in the schema namespace, and is automatically cleaned when the connection is closed. I generally encourage use of temp-tables here, check with your DB docs, schema, and/or DBA for more info here.)

The order of tables is important: by pulling all `from mytemptable` and then `left join table1` onto it, we are effectively filtering out any data from `table1` that does not include a matching `id` and `country`.

This doesn't solve the speed of data download, but some thoughts on that:

1. Each time you iterate through the queries, you have not-insignificant overhead; if there's a lot of data then this overhead should not be huge, but it's still there. Using a single query will reduce this overhead significantly.
2. Query time can also be affected by any index(ices) on the tables. Outside the scope of this discussion, but might be relevant if you have a large-ish table. If the table is not indexed efficiently (or the query is not structured well to use those indices), then each query will take a finite amount of time to "compile" and return data. Again, overhead that will be reduced with a single more-efficient query.
3. Large queries might benefit from using the command-line tool `mysql`; it is about as fast as you're going to get, and might iron over any issues in `RMySQL` and/or `DBI`. (I'm not saying they are inefficient, but ... it is unlikely that a free open-source driver will be faster than MySQL's own command-line utility.

---

As for doing this in *parallel* ...

1. You're using `parLapply` incorrectly. It accepts a single vector/list and iterates over each object in that list. You might use it iterating over the *indices* of a frame, but you cannot use it to iterate over multiple columns within that frame. This is exactly like base R's `lapply`.

   Let's show what is going on when you do your call. I'll replace it with `lapply` (because debugging in multiple processes is difficult).

   ```r
   # parLapply(clust, mtcars, function(id, country) { ... })
   lapply(mtcars, function(id, country) { browser(); 1; })
   # Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
   debug at #1: [1] 1
   id
   #  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2
   # [24] 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
   country
   # Error: argument "country" is missing, with no default
   ```

   Because the argument (`mtcars` here, `short_list` in yours) is a `data.frame`, since it is a `list`-like object, `lapply` (and `parLapply`) operate on each *column* at a time. You were hoping that it would "unzip" the data, applying the first column's value to `id` and the second column's value to `country`. In fact, the is a function that does this: `Map` (and the parallel's `clusterMap`, as I suggested in my comment). More on that later.
2. The intent of parallelizing things is to ***not*** use the `for` loop inside the parallel function. *If* `short_list` has 10 rows, *and* if your use of `parLapply` were correct, *then* you would be querying all rows 10 times, making your problem significantly worse. In pseudo-code, you'd be doing:

   ```
   parallelize for each row in short_list:
       # this portion is run simultaneously in 10 difference processes/threads
       for each row in short_list:
           query for data related to this row
   ```

Two alternatives:

1. Provide a single argument to `parLapply` representing the rows of the frame.

   ```r
   new_de <-     new_de <- parLapply(clust, seqlen(NROW(short_list)), function(rownum) {
     mydb = OpenConn(dbname = '*', user = '*', password = '*', host = '**')
     on.exit({ DBI::dbDisconnect(mydb) })
     tryCatch(
       DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb, "
         select * from table1
         where id=? and country=?
           and source_event_date >= date >= '2019-04-31' and `date` <= '2020-09-1'",
         params = list(short_list$id[rownum], short_list$country[rownum])),
       error = function(e) e)
   })
   ```
2. Use `clusterMap` for the same effect.

   ```r
   new_de <- clusterMap(clust, function(id, country) {
     mydb = OpenConn(dbname = '*', user = '*', password = '*', host = '**')
     on.exit({ DBI::dbDisconnect(mydb) })
     tryCatch(
       DBI::dbGetQuery(mydb, "
         select * from table1
         where id=? and country=?
           and source_event_date >= date >= '2019-04-31' and `date` <= '2020-09-1'",
         params = list(id, country)),
       error = function(e) e)
   }, short_list$id, short_list$country)
   ```

   If you are not familiar with `Map`, it is like "zipping" together multiple vectors/lists. For example:

   ```r
   myfun1 <- function(i) paste(i, "alone")
   lapply(1:3, myfun1)
   ### "unrolls" to look like
   list(
     myfun1(1),
     myfun1(2),
     myfun1(3)
   )

   myfun3 <- function(i,j,k) paste(i, j, k, sep = '-')
   Map(f = myfun3, 1:3, 11:13, 21:23)
   ### "unrolls" to look like
   list(
     myfun3(1, 11, 21),
     myfun3(2, 12, 22),
     myfun3(3, 13, 23)
   )
   ```

Some liberties I took in that adapted code:

1. I shifted from the `dbSendQuery`/`dbFetch` double-tap to a single call to `dbGetQuery`.
2. I'm using `DBI` functions, since `DBI` functions provide a superset of what each driver's package provides. (You're likely using some of it anyway, perhaps without realizing it.) You can switch back with no issue.
3. I added `tryCatch`, since sometimes errors can be difficult to deal with in parallel processes. This means you'll need to check the return value from each of your processes to see if either `inherits(ret, "error")` (problem) or `is.data.frame` (normal).
4. I used `on.exit` so that even if there's a problem, the connection closure should still occur.

Comment: Thanks this works nice however still I do not know how I can do it in parallel